# Unable to Log debug loggers using SLF4J + Log4J

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging, log4j, slf4j

We were using only Log4J framework in our web application and it was working fine. Now, I'm trying to integrate SLF4J + Log4J so that it will be easy for us to migrate to any kind of logging framework like Log4j2 or logback in the future.

Jars Used:

```
log4j-1.2.17.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
```

Below is the Java class which is used to load the property file

```
    static {
    final URL url = Loader.getResource("myApp_log4j.properties");
    if (url != null) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(url);
    }
```

Below is my myApp_log4J.properties file

```
 log4j.debug=true
    log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE, CA
    log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, FILE, CA

    log4j.logger.com.*=debug

 log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:\\logPath\\app.log

    log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

    log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n
    log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=10000KB
    log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=20

    log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
    log4j.appender.CA.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
    log4j.appender.CA.layout.conversionPattern=[%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n
```

After the application is started in the server. Only the Info, warn, error messages are logged in the console and in the app.log file (log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/logPath/app.log).

I want to log the debug loggers in the application. Below are the tags I've added by referring to different forums I've come across during search.

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, FILE, CA      
log4j.logger.com.*=debug
```

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: I've created a sample java project with the above mentioned configuration, placed few loggers in a class with main method. When the main class is executed, I'm able to print all the loggers; even debug.

But in the web application, I'm not able to print the debug loggers using SLF4J.